# Error 500 server javascript usando json

Tags: javascript, json

necesito controlar el error 500 server pero hasta el momento no he podido hacerlo. Se que el error se da cuando no me devuelve nada desde el archivo consultado pero no se como hacer para que cuando eso pase me aparezca un cartel indicando que eso sucedio. En su lugar me sale ** POST ../coordenas_cmd.php 500 (Internal Server Error)**

La estructura del codigo es la siguiente

Answer (score 3):

Jquery `post` tiene, ademas del callback que obtiene los datos tiene unos eventos que son `fail`, `done` y `always`.

Lo que debes hacer es trabajar el evento `fail` de esta manera:

```
$.post('./coordenas_cmd.php', {latitudOrigen:latitudOrigen,longitudOrigen:longitudOrigen,latitudDestino:latitudDestino,longitudDestino:longitudDestino,cli:cli,valor_cuadra:valor_cuadra }, function() {
   // hacer algo
})
.fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
  console.log(status) // 500
  // manejo del error
})
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias amigo